# Cognos, How can I track all burst reports and recipients

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

In Cognos environment there are many reports scheduled to be delivered to user's  email id. How can I track all those reports without doing lot's of manual work.

Using audit package's `Run Jobs` and `Run Reports` I am not able to track reports which are scheduled to email burst as Run Report doesn't provide information on mode of bursting of a report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The recipients are not directly stored in the content store anywhere... they are pulled from a query within the report.

If the report is saving output, you can set it to retain the saved outputs for a few days.  Every version that was sent out will be saved.

Outside that, you will have to do manual work.  Get into the report, find the query that feeds into the burst, and run the query manually to see who it is built for.

If you have multiple burst reports in your environment, consider switching to use a table that stores all of your burst recipients.  Then performing monitoring/maintenance of burst users will be a simple query away.

Comment: I also got an Idea to get message log of SMTP server for subject line  matching report name. This will give all report and recipient name.

Comment: Still exploring some way to get it using Motio PI